# Android react-native scrollView can not scroll to the top when keyboard show

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, textinput

Android react-native scrollView contain multiple textinput, height greater than the height of the screen when the keyboard pops up , the entire page will go on top , and you can not scroll to the top

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this core component

> Open sourced KeyboardAvoidingView Summary: KeyboardAvoidingView is a
>   component we built internally to solve the common problem of views
>   that need to move out of the way of the virtual keyboard.
>
> KeyboardAvoidingView can automatically adjust either its position or
>   bottom padding based on the position of the keyboard.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8b78846a9501ef9c5ce9d1e18ee104bfae76af2e